# how to output debugging messages from install.ps1 in NuGet

Tags: powershell, nuget

I am developing a NuGet package, including an `install.ps1` script which runs during the package installation.  I would like to be able to output messages from my script and also output the results of running `.bat` files from within my sript.

Here is my `install.ps1`:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
Write-Output "Running install.ps1 for MyPkg"
Set-Location $toolsPath
.\helper.bat | Write-Output
```

When I install my package in Visual Studio, then I look in the `Package Manager` option in the `Output` page, I see:

```
Executing script file 'C:\Test\packages\MyPkg.1\tools\install.ps1'.
```

and it seems the script is working (I can tell in other ways that `helper.bat` ran), but I don't see any of the output.   How can I get the output working?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I could not get the output when installing from the NuGet Package Manager Dialog, I'll dig a bit later to see where it's going.

But you should be able to see it when installing from the Nuget console (Tools->Library Package Manager->Package Manager Console). The output went directly in the console. Example :

```
PM> uninstall-package samplepackage
hello from unninstal.ps1
Successfully removed 'samplepackage 1.0.0' from WebApplication24.
```

unninstal.ps1 :

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
Write-Host "hello from unninstal.ps1"
```

Comment: That works!  And  .\helper.bat | Write-Host  shows the output of the batch file.  So my problem was Write-Output instead of Write-Host.